# How to remove all occurrences of a character in a dataframe?

Tags: python, string, pandas, replace

I have a dataframe with multiple columns and most have special characters like $, % or ^ and so on... How can I delete these characters throughout the entire data frame? I only know how to delete by column, for example:

```py
df['Column'] = df['Column'].str.replace('^\d+','')
```

Comment: Use [dataframe.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

Comment: This is actually a good question. `dataframe.replace` does not replace any special characters like `$`, `%` etc.

Comment: Is there a problem with iterating over `for col in df.columns`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just noticed that [pandas.DataFrame.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) does not work with special characters like `$`, `%`, `^` etc. So, you can use following snippet to get rid of these special characters from the whole dataframe. We need to make sure that a certain column is of type `string` before applying [str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.api.types import is_string_dtype

f = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':['f;','d:','sda$sd'],
                   'D':['s%','d;','d^p'],
                   'E':[5,3,6],
                   'F':[7,4,3]})
```

`f` looks like follows.

```
   A  B       C    D  E  F
0  1  4      f;   s%  5  7
1  2  5      d:   d;  3  4
2  3  6  sda$sd  d^p  6  3
```

Now use a loop to replace the strings.

```
for col in f.columns:
        if is_string_dtype(f[col]):
            f[col] = f[col].str.replace('[^A-Za-z0-9-\s]+', '')
```

Output:

```
   A  B      C   D  E  F
0  1  4      f   s  5  7
1  2  5      d   d  3  4
2  3  6  sdasd  dp  6  3
```

**UPDATE:**
The pandas version `0.24.1` does not replace some special characters, but versions `0.23.4` and `0.25.1` do work. So if you have any of these working versions, you can easily use `pandas.DataFrame.replace` to delete the special characters as follows. Make sure to escape these characters with `\`.

```
f = f.replace({'\$':'', '\^':'','%':''}, regex=True)
```

This results in the same output as above.

Comment: great answer, I would just add \s in the end so the code doesn't delete white spaces as well, so it would be: [^A-Za-z0-9-\s]+

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
pandas.DataFrame.replace(to_replace, value)
```

The parameters accept regex and it should cover the whole df. Hope this helps.

Here's the documentation on this method:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html#pandas.DataFrame.replace